# Materialize tab shrinks fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, materialize

I have a fullcalendar interface for a Timelog tool made with flask. My problem is that the 2nd tab containing the fullcalendar isn't rendered. when its render with thing i tried he shrink itself at the 1st click on an event and "unshrinks" when the window is resized. Its pretty wierd

Ive read many question about this issue but noone of them provided a working solution. I use materialize tabs. Appart from setting the fullcalendar as active tab i am out of ideas

```
    <div class="row" id="tab_content">
     <div class="col s12">
     <ul class="tabs">
     <li class="tab col s6"><a href="#tasks" name="tab1">Tasks View</a></li>
     <li class="tab col s6"><a href="#calendar" name="tab2" class="active">Calendar View</a></li>
     </ul>
     <h4 id='name_human'>{{ name }}</h4>
     <button id="delete_event" type="" class="btn btn-secondary">delete Timelog</button>
     <button id="add_event" type="" class="btn btn-secondary">Add Timelog</button>
     <input  type="hidden" name="select_date" id="select_date" value="">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tasks" class="col s12">
   <div class="table-responsive">
   </div>
  </div>


  <div id="calendar" class="col s12">
   <div id='calendar'>
   </div>
  </div>





   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {


    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: ['dayGrid','moment', "interaction"],
        weekends: false,
        selectable: true,
        droppable: true,
        displayEventTime: false,
        editable: true,
        themeSystem : 'standart',
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
          handleWindowResize : true,

        eventRender: function(info) {
          var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                placement: 'top',
                trigger: 'hover',
                container: 'body'
              });
          },
        select: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
          $("#add_event").css("visibility","visible");
          $("#select_date").val(date.startStr);
          today = date.start;
          tomorrow = new Date(today);
          tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1)
          if(date.end.getTime() != tomorrow.getTime()){
            calendar.unselect() ;
          }
          },
        unselect: function(jsEvent, view) {
          $("#add_event").css("visibility","hidden");
        },
        eventDrop: function(info) {
            if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
              info.revert();
            }else{
              var date_millis = Date.parse(info.event.start);
              var new_date = new Date(date_millis)
              var year = new_date.getFullYear()
              var month = parseInt(new_date.getMonth())+1
              var day = new_date.getDate()
              string_date = year + "-" + parseInt(month) +"-"+day;
            Update_timelog(info.event.id ,string_date)
            }
          },
        eventClick: function(info) {
          $("#delete_event").css("visibility","visible");
          $('body>.tooltip').remove();
          var listEvent = calendar.getEvents()
          for (var i = 0; listEvent.length>i; i++){
            listEvent[i].setProp('borderColor','');
          }
          info.event.setProp('borderColor','red');   
          },
                  events: {{hour}}
          });
          calendar.render();
```

I've tried the following (partially working, rendering the event but all the functionnalities (select drag and drop) are gone the the calendar is shrinked

```
   if ($('.fc-day-grid-container').height() == 0) {
     $('.fc-widget-content').height("100%")
     $('.fc-day-grid-container').height("100%")
     $('.fc-week').height("120px")
   }

   $('.tabs li').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var baseURL = window.location.origin;
     var url = $(this).children().first().attr('href');
     window.location.href = baseURL+"/main" + url;
     if (url == "#calendar") {
       //calendar.render();
     }
  })
```

photo link of what it looks 
https://ibb.co/vL2H0ds
https://ibb.co/Rgd9SDz

Comment: Have you tried executing the calendar's [updateSize](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/updateSize) method each time the tab becomes visible? fullCalendar automaticaly adjusts itself to the dimensions of the containing element, and if that element keeps changing its size, or being hidden and shown (or deleted and re-created, or however materialize manages the tabs) then it might get a bit confused. If materialize lets you hook into the event when a tab becomes visible, you could execute that method then so that fullCalendar can adjust itself correctly. It's worth a try, I think.

Comment: i will try this out

Comment: It works the way i want appart from the fact that i have to double click on the tab to activate the updatesize() but this is my job to work it out. Thanks a lot

Comment: Great. If you get it fully working you should add it as an Answer below in case others have a similar problem :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by ADyson, i have my update url tab listener fireing updateSize() which was a solution to my issue. I wish i could fire it after the tab is shown rather than an on click but for now i'll go for a double click on the tab, it works decently.

here is the code i used for this, if you have any improvement i'll gladly take it.

```
$('.tabs li').click(function(e){
 var baseURL = window.location.origin;
 var url = $(this).children().first().attr('href');
 window.location.href = baseURL+"/main" + url;
 if(url == "#calendar"){
  setTimeout(function(){calendar.updateSize()},150)
 }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by using a `MutationObserver` on the div holding the tab content:

```
// listening for the tab content getting visible
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    if ($("#upcoming").css('display') != 'none') {
       calendar.updateSize();
    };
});

observer.observe($('#upcoming')[0], {attributes: true});
```